# "on hold" Question is actually removed

Tags: support, on-hold

When looking through my helpful flags I saw that alot of questions I had where "[on hold]", like this:

[image]

But when I clicked on the question I got the 'Page not found' notice saying that the question is removed. Since [on hold] should mean that the question is still there but just closed I find it misleading that the question is actually removed. Isn't it an option to change the [on hold] to [removed] or something like that?

Comment: The [grayish red background](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) means "removed".

Comment: @Antony Oh, I didn't know that. I assumed it was normal since all of my flagged posts have that background. (Didn't notice they were all removed^^)

Comment: 'Removed' is slightly misleading, but this is the same behaviour as closed and deleted questions. They aren't really removed from the system, they're just hidden from anyone below a certain rep, and you get the page-not-found message.